# How to position bottom of div above top of its container

Tags: css, css-position

I'm working on a HTML/CSS module that functions like a modal but looks like a tooltip

```
<aside class="learn is-learn-top">
    <a class="learn__trigger" href="#learn-01">
        <span class="learn__icon">[icon]</span>
        <span class="learn__summary">Click here to learn more about TV pilots from Samual Jackson...who else</span>
    </a>
    <div class="learn__content" id="learn-01">
        <a class="learn__close learn__x" href="#!">[close]</a>
        <div>
          Well, the way they make shows is, they make one show. That show's called a pilot. Then they show that show to the people who make shows, and on the strength of that one show they decide if they're going to make more shows.
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

I'm using

```
.learn__content:not(:target) {
    display: none;
}
```

to keep that hidden unless the trigger is clicked. I'm trying to position `.learn__content` (which may be of varying height) above `.learn` like tooltip. How can I position it like this without using an explicit height? **[Here's what a have so far.](http://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/xGopjQ)**

```
.learn {
    position: relative;
}

.learn__content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    background: gold;
}

.is-learn-top .learn__content {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    top: -100%;
}
```

but `-100%` doesn't seem to give the necessary offset.

Comment: What if accumulated comments height exceeds the available space - ending up too far beneath the top window edge?

Comment: `top: -100%;` positions the element up the height of the container, versus the height of the tooltip (the former would be nice, huh). It may be interesting to note that Bootstrap uses JS for tooltips. Assuming that is because of the need for position based on box size.

Comment: I know it's possible with JavaScript but I think it's possible with just CSS alone and I hope to figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transform: translateY(-100%)
```

And make sure you use `WebKit`, and `moz` if needed

Comment: This works as long as the content inside generates box height. At first I was using `position: absolute` for layout inside and that was causing the box height to be less than the full box.

Answer (score 2):

Basically using `bottom: 100%;` (on an absolute positioned element),
but let's see another example using

**label** and **checkbox**

```css
aside{ padding-top:100px; /*JUST FOR DEMO*/ }
.modal{
  display:    inline-block;
  position:   relative;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.modal>div{
  pointer-events: none;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:   absolute;
  bottom:     100%;
  left:       50%;
  width:      150px;
  padding:    15px;
  background: #eee;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity:    0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform:  translateY(30px) translateX(-50%);
}
.modal>input{
  position:   absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  height:     0;
}
.modal>input:checked+div{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:    1;
  transform:  translateY(0px) translateX(-50%);
}
.modal>div:after{
  content: "×";
  pointer-events:auto;
  position:   absolute;
  top:        5px;
  right:      10px;
  cursor:     pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<aside>  

  This is some text

  <label class="modal">
    click to find out
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex inventore aperiam!
    </div>
  </label>

  and more text here

  <label class="modal">
    click me!
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      Like it?! Share and rate!
    </div>
  </label>

  and happy coding

</aside>
```

As you can see above, I'm really worried about where the tooltip will appear. Better use a JS script or a jQuery plugin - that way you don't need to worry if the text will be readable or hidden somewhere below the window edges.